# How can you see Python typing conflicts in Vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-typing

I have been adding python types to my function parameters and returns for some time now, but I haven't figured out how to make use of these beyond the popup hints when I hover over a parameter.

Is there a way to get red underlining or some other report feedback showing me locations where the type of a parameter being passed does not match the parameter's typing definition?

Answer (score 1):

You could enable `mypy` linting. Add this in the settings.json file:

```
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know VSC doesn't support python type hinting. If you really need type hinting maybe try downloading the Community Edition of Pycharm

It has type checking and hinting features and is completely free.